# Webpack require moment with global reference

Tags: webpack, momentjs

So I've tried multiple approaches but no matter what I do 'moment' isn't available globally. Very frustrating. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: "./app/vendor.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader")
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=app/img/[name].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery",
          moment: "moment"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("app/styles.css")
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "./app/[name].bundle.js"
    }
}
```

if you notice below, I had to use window.d3 to make d3 available globally because adding it to the webpack.providerplugin wasn't working with d3 specifically. same thing with moment, only the window.moment and var moment = require isn't working either.

```
window.d3 = require('d3');

require("jquery");
require('jquery-ui/ui/core');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker');

require('lodash');
require('angular');

require('chosen-js');
require('chosen-js/chosen.css');

var moment = require('moment/min/moment-with-locales.js');
require('moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js')
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader ? ProvidePlugin is used to load a module without explicitly loading them, so that it will behave like a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arjun — Yes the expose-loader works for me. Thank you! https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

```
require('expose-loader?moment!moment');
```